# Errors While Compiling ffmpeg and opencv

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile [this example](http://goppodu.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/ffmpeg-with-opencv/)

on Ubunto. This is the compile command:

```
    g++ video.cpp -o video `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lpthread -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz
```

and this is the errors I'm getting:

```
     /usr/local/include/libavutil/common.h:173:47: error: ‘UINT64_C’ was not declared in this scope
     video.cpp: In member function ‘int FFread::init(char*)’:
     video.cpp:24:56: error: ‘av_open_input_file’ was not declared in this scope
     video.cpp:28:5: warning: ‘int av_find_stream_info(AVFormatContext*)’ is deprecated      (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1266) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     video.cpp:28:35: warning: ‘int av_find_stream_info(AVFormatContext*)’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1266) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     video.cpp:32:36: error: ‘dump_format’ was not declared in this scope
     video.cpp:37:48: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
```

Please advise.
Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: Please reformat your question by using the code tag (curly braces: {} icon) in order to make the error output more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling FFmpeg libraries from a C++ program. Are you wrapping the #include calls to the relevant headers in

```
extern "C" { ... }
```

constructs? The headers don't have automatic C++ support.

**EDIT:**

I read the linked example source; it does the right thing.

I think the problem is version discrepancy. The example is over 2 years old and the FFmpeg APIs have moved on. You may have to upgrade the API calls on your own.

Answer (score 5):

See libav faq.txi

@I'm using Libav from within my C++ application but the linker complains about missing symbols which seem to be available.

Libav is a pure C project using C99 math features, in order to enable C++
to use them you have to append -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS to your CXXFLAGS

Answer (score 0):

as far as i remember, you should use cmake for building opencv. cmake inspects your environment in terms of c compiler, library support, thread libraries etc. and sets some flags in compilation automatically. so do not try to compile it yourself. just follow the steps in here http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide_Linux